# What is the "It was my understanding, that there would be no math" quote based on?

Tags: united-states, debate

There is a [notorious SNL skit](https://vimeo.com/65921206) where Chevy Chase portrays Gerald Ford at a debate, and to a budgetary question replies:

> It was my understanding that there would be no math during the debates. Now, I am prepared to answer any domestic questions, perhaps something about me and Betty?

What debate was this based on? Did Ford majorly flub some budgetary question—what was it?

Comment: Chevy Chase was for for attacking President Ford and pretending that he was clumsy and ignorant. As I recall, it had nothing to do with reality.

Comment: @sabbahillel was that impression from one of the three debates in particular, or just synthesized from the whole of Ford's persona, in and out of them?

Comment: This included Chevy Chase constantly pretending to fall and is from my memory of what was going on then in general. I do not recall debate specifics.

Comment: It was more a comment on American society at the time. There was a common expression "there won't be any math on the test" to reassure students. The closest I could find to an online source in 2m of searching: http://www.chronicle.com/forums/index.php?topic=161061.15;imode and http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~grahne/comp232/cs-needs-math.pdf